# Why is my proof that $L^1(\nu) = L^1(|\nu|)$ for signed measure $\nu$ incorrect?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

The following exercise is in Folland:

Let $\nu$ be a signed measure on $(X, \mathcal{M})$ show that $L^1(\nu) = L^1(|\nu|)$.

My attempt:
Consider $f \in L^1(\nu)$ then we know that

$$\int |f| d\nu = \int |f| d\nu^+ - \int |f| d\nu^- < \infty$$

This can only happen iff $\int |f| d\nu^+ < \infty$ and $\int |f| d\nu^- < \infty$. Thus, we see that

$$\int |f| d|\nu| = \int |f| d\nu^+ + \int |f| d\nu^- < \infty$$

So we must have $f \in L^1(|\nu|)$. Since all these steps were two ways, we have also that $f \in L^1(\nu)$.

This "proof" seems too simple and others seem to be giving me the same idea that this is not correct. Where is the flaw and how can I fix it?

Comment: What's the exact definition of $L^1(\nu)$ for a signed measure $\nu$?

Comment: Remembering that $L^1$ is really a set of equivalence classes, presumably part of what's being asserted is that the equivalence classes are the same, so you would have to show that $f = g$ $\nu$-a.e. (however that's defined) iff $f = g$ $|\nu|$-a.e.

Comment: @NateEldredge In Folland it has been defined as $L^1(\nu) = L^1(\nu^+) \cap L^1(\nu^-)$ where $\nu = \nu^+ - \nu^-$ is the Jordan decomposition of $\nu$.

Comment: Okay, so then your statement that $\int |f| d\nu^+ < \infty$ and $\int |f| d\nu^- < \infty$ is already the definition.  The line about $\int f d\nu^+ - \int f d\nu^-$ is not the definition and would have to be justified.

Comment: But there is still another statement to be shown: that $f = g$ $|\nu|$-a.e. iff $f = g$ $\nu^+$-a.e. and $f=g$ $\nu^-$-a.e.

Comment: @NateEldredge In Folland it is given that 

$$\int  f d\nu = \int f d\nu^+ - \int f d\nu^-$$

as definition for integrating with respect to a signed measure.

Comment: Yes, but the definition of "$f \in L^1(\nu)$" is not "$\int |f|\,d\nu < \infty$", despite what the notation might suggest.  The definition is "$f \in L^1(\nu^+) \cap L^1(\nu^-)$".

Comment: @NateEldredge Ah understood. So yes I agree with you then that $\int |f| d\nu^+, \int |f| d\nu^- < \infty$ follows from definition. So if I modify my proof to reflect this, then is it correct? Meaning, is everything that follows in my proof after that step correct?

Comment: Yes, the rest seems fine.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thank you very much for the help.